# jQuery UI : Sidebar is also droppable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

When I drag n drop the element into the area where I have to drop it is working fine but when I release the element inside the sidebar then also it is droppable why?

Here is the sidebar code

html

```
<div class="my_fab js-toggleSidebar"></div>
  <div id="templateWrapper">
    <div id="textTemplate" class="template">
        <div>Text</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

js

```
$(document).on('click', '.js-toggleSidebar', function() {
    $( '#templateWrapper' ).toggleClass( 'sidebar-closed' );
});
```

css

```
#templateWrapper {position: fixed;
    color: #ffffff;
    z-index: 10;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #1F1F1F;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 280px;
    -webkit-transition: transform 320ms ease;
    -moz-transition: transform 320ms ease;
    -ms-transition: transform 320ms ease;
    -o-transition: transform 320ms ease;
    transition: transform 320ms ease; }

 #templateWrapper.sidebar-closed {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-100%);
    -o-transform: translateX(-100%);
    transform: translateX(-100%); 
}
```

AND

[Here is my jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/MyTests/9eafeo1n/2/)

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MyTests/9eafeo1n/4/)

Comment: Your text template has a height of 100% that is filling up the entire sidebar making it seem like the entire sidebar is draggable :]

Comment: @Sean_Codes I have updated my fiddle but the problem is the same. I have hide the height but after that the scroll bar is to small

Comment: You'll want to get rid of that overflow:scroll and let the textWrapper do the scrolling right now you have height:100vh on that. It will be easier to use min-height:100vh then if there is bunches of text in there it will start scrolling once past that point

Comment: @Sean_Codes  but if I had more elements means( if suppose I have text 1, 2 ----- ,20 so I can not scroll down )

Comment: Add `overflow-y:auto;` also to your `#templateWrapper` ❤️

Comment: @Sean_Codes Still the same problem could you please make a fiddle for me of your example

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144722/discussion-between-user7791702-and-sean-codes).